# Why do I get "stack level too deep" from method_missing in irb 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, irb, method-missing

Scenario:

```
-bash-3.2$ irb -f
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > @v = {}
 => {} 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > def method_missing(sym, *args); @v[sym]; end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > a
(irb):2: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
-bash-3.2$
```

I ran with -f to avoid loading any irbrc stuff.
I'm expecting to get nil when I input `a`. What's going on, and is there a workaround? I tried wrapping `a` with a `begin`/`rescue Exception` block but that didn't do anything.

This also happens with 1.9.2, but not 1.9.1.

More strange behavior:

```
-bash-3.2$ irb -f
irb(main):001:0> @v = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> def method_missing(sym, *args); @v[sym]; end; 5.times { p a }
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
=> 5
irb(main):003:0> a
(irb):2: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
-bash-3.2$
```

This tells me that there's a bug in irb, or that some obscure bug in ruby is being triggered by irb. Also, after defining method_missing, even methods that exist like `local_variables` or `eval` cause the error.

Comment: I get a variety of errors under IRB with defining `method_missing`, errors that don't occur outside IRB. For example: `irb> def method_missing(*a); p a; end; => nil; [:to_hash]; [:to_str]; C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:45:in raise: can't convert TypeError to String (TypeError#to_str gives Array) (TypeError)`

Comment: Random guess (not an answer): irb leans on and existing monkeypatch to `method_missing`, and redefining it blows things up. [This](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5077) looks vaguely related.

Comment: @Phrogz That bug report was a bit entertaining. But I don't think it applies in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like defining it as a singleton method works:

```
def self.method_missing(sym, *args); @v[sym]; end
```

Defining it as a top-level method replaces BasicObject#method_missing, which probably affected some irb internals like Phrogz said.