# Cannot define method_missing in top Object

Tags: ruby, method-missing

When I try define(by loading script&just typing in the pry) method_missing in pry it just exit to console(cmd on windows xp).
When I try typing it on the IRB, it goes into infinite loop or when I try loading the script(irb m.rb) it shows something like this:

```
D:\programowanie\Ruby>irb m.rb
m.rb(main):001:0> def method_missing name, *args, &block
m.rb(main):002:1>   puts 'method is missing'
m.rb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
m.rb(main):004:0>
m.rb(main):005:0* some_missing_method("lol")method is missing
m.rb(main):005:0*
method is missing
method is missing
method is missing
m.rb(main):005:0>
method is missing
method is missing
method is missing
method is missing
```

and it exits to the console(cmd)
Here is my code:

```
def method_missing name, *args, &block
  puts 'method is missing'
  nil
end

some_missing_method("lol")
```

When I return something else it doesn't go into infinite loop but shows error instead(only first few lines are changing):
Number:

```
method is missing
method is missing
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:45:in `raise': can't convert TypeError to String (TypeError#to_str gives Fixnum) (Typ
eError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:45:in `rescue in readline'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:39:in `readline'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/input-method.rb:115:in `gets'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:138:in `block in eval_input'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in `buf_input'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:103:in `getc'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:205:in `match_io'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:75:in `match'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:286:in `token'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:262:in `lex'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

String:

```
method is missing
method is missing
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:45:in `rescue in readline': this_is_string (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:39:in `readline'
        (..)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine for me. 1.9.3p392

Comment: Maybe it's the windows env?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes for me too.. working..

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how does windows env destroing my code? And what OS are you 2 using?

Answer (score 2):

So this requires some understanding of Ruby's class/object/module hierarchy, as well as some understanding of how tools like IRB and Pry work. Take a look at this, which may blow your mind as it did mine - https://web.archive.org/web/20160319051340/http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html.

As for IRB and Pry, I don't know much about their code, but I know they basically work by reading your input and eval'ing + lots of magic.

As you seem to already know, when you're in irb/pry, you're inside the `Object` scope, from which nearly everything else inherits, *including IRB and Pry themselves*. So overriding something in `Object`, like `method_missing`, might change the behavior of everything that descends from it (i.e. Everything) including IRB/Pry. Pry is probably overriding `method_missing` itself to do something very important, and your change is breaking that.

You might try this as an interesting experiment:

```
def method_missing name, *args, &block
  puts "method '#{name}' is missing"
end
```

That might give you *some* idea why it's happening, but the short answer is **don't do it**. Encapsulate your code into its own Module so that it doesn't interfere with anything else.

And I might be confusing myself here, but this *might* get things working again. It should restore whatever expectations Pry has about `Object#method_missing`:

```
def method_missing name, *args, &block
  puts "method '#{name}' is missing"
  super
end
```

**Edit**

True, I don't think `BasicObject#method_missing` exists. But that's okay, because the above `super` will raise an error like "NoMethodError: undefined method missing_method' for #". That more or less restores the behavior that pry/irb seem to be expecting: that `Object#method_missing` should ultimately raise a `NoMethodError`. That should fix the infinite recursive loop.

However, a better solution (aside from not overwriting `Object#method_missing` in the first place) might be to raise a `NoMethodError` yourself after doing whatever else you have to do:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  puts "method '#{name}' is missing"
  # important stuff
  raise NoMethodError, name
end
```

My guess is that pry is rescuing from a `NoMethodError` in some loop. So if it's never raised, the loop continues forever. If that's right, then the above should fix it. Not that I recommend it.

Comment: If you overwrite `method_missing`, then `super` isn't going to help you. `super` delegates to *overridden* methods, *overwritten* methods are just gone. Your code will delegate to the `method_missing` implementation in `Object`'s superclass. Well, in 1.8, *there is no* superclass, and in 1.9+, there is `BasicObject` which doesn't implement `method_missing`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag but I can do this: 
b=BasicObject.new
#<BasicObject:0x1cbb3c4>
b.missing_method
NoMethodError: undefined method `missing_method' for #<BasicObject:0x3976788>`
And super, indeed, doesn't work. It's indeed pry/irb problem. And bioneurelnet's method shows, more or less, `to_ary/to_hash` missing on `String/Fixnum`.

Comment: @bioneuralnet raise doesn't work and beside it needs string(so `name.to_s`). Based on: [google translated Chinese text](http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fruby-china.org%2Ftopics%2F8120) & [SO.com answer on another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491462/why-do-i-get-stack-level-too-deep-from-method-missing-in-irb-1-9-3)singleton method works: def self.method_missing *a
   puts 'missing'
   super
 end
it works, BUT still I don't know 'magic' that destroy it, so if someone has better(more detailed) information please post.